# I want to make a function which does not uses any inbuilt function in java script and removes the white spaces at both ends of receiving string

Tags: javascript

```
function func(str) {
        var a = "" , c;
        var b = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            c = str.charAt(i);

            if((str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\t') || b > 0)
            {
        a += c;
        b++;
    }
return a;    
}
```

So far the function I have removes the whitespace from the left side but I cant figure out for the remove the whitespace from the right side. Anyone got any suggestions.

Comment: just try checking from both ends of string and remove both ends in one pass and if both doesn't find any more space chars break the loop

Comment: What's `b` supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `return` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: `charAt` is a builtin function, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's cleanest if you don't try to do it all in one loop. I'd use a loop to find the start, to find the end, and to copy the part of the string you want. You're still pretty much just iterating once, but you have each task separate from the others.

```js
function isSpace(c) {
  return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'
}

function slice(str, from, to) {
  var start = from >= 0 ? from : 0;
  var end = to <= str.length ? to : str.length;

  var a = "";
  while (start < end) a += str[start++];
  return a;
}

function trim(str) {
  var first = 0, last = str.length-1;

  while (isSpace(str[first])) first++; // find trimmed start
  while (isSpace(str[last])) last--;   // find trimmed end
  
  return slice(str, first, last+1); // create the desired substring
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(trim("  foo bar  ")));
```

Comment: I would even factor out the `function slice(str, from, to) { … }`

Answer (score 0):

Use the same logic you already have to do the end of the string, but just loop starting at the end and change how you build 'a':

```
function reverseFunc(str) {
    var a = "" , c;
    var b = 0;
    for(var i = str.length-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            c = str.charAt(i);

            if((str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\t') || b > 0)
            {
                a = c + a;
                b++;
            }
        }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I tried reversing the code but it's just reversing the array and displaying it

Comment: Did you not try the code I posted? I've already tested it, it does take the end bit of the string off.